# iOS Accessing Dictionary

Tags: ios, plist

I have a plist which looks like this. I usually access using the following lines of code:

[image]

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
CGFloat redFloat = (CGFloat)[[plistDict objectForKey:@"red"] floatValue];
```

However as it is nested - how do I access the colour red in BackgroundColour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely: reading `plist` into a dictionary gives you a dictionary of dictionaries, so you need to access `BackgroundColour` first:

```
CGFloat redFloat = (CGFloat)[[[plistDict objectForKey:@"BackgroundColour"] objectForKey:@"red"] floatValue];
```

New syntax lets you write it with fewer characters:

```
CGFloat redFloat = (CGFloat)[plistDict[@"BackgroundColour"][@"red"] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `valueForKeyPath:` to shortcut too:

```
CGFloat redFloat = (CGFloat)[[plistDict valueForKeyPath:@"BackgroundColour.red"] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat redFloat = [[[plistDict objectForKey:@"BackgroundColour"] objectForKey:@"red"] floatValue];
```

Comment: Even after you fix the name of the `@"BackgroundColour"` key, that would be an invalid cast, because `red` is a string.